# ASP.NET MVC: Generate URLs without specifying the actionName

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pylons

This is how I generate a URL in ASP.NET MVC currently:

```
Url.Action("Index", new { page = 2 })
```

In previous frameworks I have used, there were special url functions which created a url based on the current url, only modifying the parts you wanted to change. This is in Pylons:

```
{{ url.current(page=2) }}
```

This would come in handy with partial views, where the partial view may be showing a list of items but not necessarily know which controller they belong to.

Two questions - why is such an obviously useful feature missing from ASP.NET MVC, and is there some common alternative way of doing what I mentioned with partial views? Maybe I'm approaching partial views completely wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is such an obviously useful feature missing from ASP.NET MVC

What makes you think that such feature is missing:

```
string url = Url.Action(null, new { page = 2 });
```

or:

```
string url = Url.RouteUrl(new { page = 2 });
```

Comment: I didn't know you could pass null, but it still doesn't solve my problem, because you have specify all of the route arguments otherwise it doesn't include them. So if I have /search?s=billy, it simply drops the billy. This forces me to include the search string in my list partial view, when ideally the list shouldn't be concerned with what the url is.

Comment: The answer to this is here if anyone needs it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919851/asp-net-mvc-generate-url-based-off-of-the-current-url-and-maintain-querystring

Comment: @NoPyGod Please check the question you linked on the comment above, I've added an answer to it that you may find useful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919851/generate-url-based-off-of-the-current-url-and-maintain-querystring/21029530