# Generate URL based off of the current URL and maintain QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a partial view for displaying a list of items, I use this partial view in several different places. Inside this partial view I use a paginator -

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action(null, new { page = page }))
```

This results in the paginator showing page urls for whatever Action and View i'm already looking at.

Problem is, on my search page I use a query string for the search string, and the Url.Action method does not include existing querystring parameters.

Instead of /Search?s=bla&page=3 I end up with /Search?page=3

How can I generate a url using the existing query string?

Edit:

Here is my code

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.Add(
        "Search",
        new SearchRoute("Search", new MvcRouteHandler())
        {
            Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(
                new { controller = "Search", action = "Index" })
        }); 


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Call", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }


        );



    }

    public class SearchRoute : Route
    {
        public SearchRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
            : base(url, routeHandler)
        {
        }

        public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Url);

            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            {

                string s = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["s"];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                    values.Add("s", s);

            }

            return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a custom route, you can preserve the query string because most Url generation logic uses the route to generate the URL. In this case I am checking the Request object for a query string called XXX and adding it into the route if it exists, you can make it more generic if you like.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class PreserveQueryStringRoute : Route
{
    public PreserveQueryStringRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, routeHandler)
    {
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            values = new RouteValueDictionary(values);   //this is the bug fix!

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["XXX"]))
                values.Add("XXX", HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["XXX"]);

        }

        var path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
        return path;
    }
}
```

Register the route as per normal in the global.ascx (though probably not for such a generic match as I have below)

```
        routes.Add(
            "Default",
            new PreserveQueryStringRoute("{controller}/{action}/{id}", new MvcRouteHandler())
            {
                Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional })
            });
```

Edit:

Ok, here's an update.. its a bug fix, and an example of how to register the route (See corrected code above for bug fix)

Here's how to register it:

```
    routes.Add(      
    "Search",      
    new SearchRoute("Search", new MvcRouteHandler())      
    {      
        Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(      
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Index" })      
    });
```

Comment: Fantastic. You da man. If anyone else uses this, remember to put the call to Routes.Add above the default route.

Comment: It's putting the query string on all of the urls generated on my search page. Can that be fixed? I only need the query string on search urls.

Comment: And infact it doesn't matter where I am, if I put xxx=something in my query string, it'll be added to all generated urls.

Comment: The way I registered the route above (just as an example) means that it'll match pretty much any route.. You should register it in a less generic way for it to only affect url generation for specific pages

Comment: GetVirtualPath is supposed to check that the url matches. By overriding it, and adding a value to the route before you've even checked if the url matches, you end up with the querystring being added on every url regardless of whether it's the one specified in the url. I wasted a few hours trying to get your solution to work.

Comment: GetVirtualPath isn't supposed to check if the url matches, that happens in RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath. That iterates over all registered routes and checks to see if the route matches the constraints. Then it'll call the GetVirtualPath method of the first route which matches. There are 2 reasons why the above method could add a query string parameter to every generated URL. 1) it matches the SearchRoute when it shouldn't. Make sure constraints prevent this (even a IRouteConstraint if really necessary. 2) There was a bug in my original code which modified the original...

Comment: RouteValueDictionary which meant the route would only need to matched at once for it to add the query string parameters to all subsequent urls

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do this:

I've implemented a few extension methods to convert query string to `RouteValueDictionary` and set individual items in it:

```
public static class RouteValueDictionaryExtensions
{
    public static RouteValueDictionary ToRouteValues(this NameValueCollection queryString)
    {
        if (queryString == null || queryString.HasKeys() == false) 
            return new RouteValueDictionary();

        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
        foreach (string key in queryString.AllKeys)
            routeValues.Add(key, queryString[key]);

        return routeValues;
    }

    public static RouteValueDictionary Set(this RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string key, string value)
    {
        routeValues[key] = value;
        return routeValues;
    }

    public static RouteValueDictionary Merge(this RouteValueDictionary primary, RouteValueDictionary secondary)
    {
        if (primary == null || primary.Count == 0)
        {
            return secondary ?? new RouteValueDictionary();
        }

        if (secondary == null || secondary.Count == 0)
            return primary;

        foreach (var pair in secondary)
            primary[pair.Key] = pair.Value;

        return primary;
    }

    public static RouteValueDictionary Merge(this RouteValueDictionary primary, object secondary)
    {
        return Merge(primary, new RouteValueDictionary(secondary));
    }
}
```

This makes it possible to create links such as:

```
Url.RouteUrl(Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues().Set("Key", "Value"))
```

Or this:

```
Url.RouteUrl(Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues().Merge(new {key = "value"}))
```

I can also chain these extension methods to achieve more flexibility:

```
Url.RouteUrl(Request.QueryString.ToRouteValues().Set("Key", "Value").Set("AnotherKey", "AnotherValue"))
```